# Transact SQL Query-Pivot-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table `MySeekCatTable` with a structure:

```
       SeekId  CatId

        J       1<= i<=45
```

in this table every `SeekId` has three `CatId`.
The table `MySeekCatTable` references two table with foreign keys:

the first table `SeekTable` with `SeekId` as primary key is like:

```
        SeekId  Name

          1     John

          2     Kelly
```

the second table `CatTable` with `CatId` as primary key is like:

```
        CatId   Name

          1     Cat1

          2     Cat2
```

My need is that I have to write a query that gives for every `SeekId` three of its `CatId` in the format:

```
      SeekId      A          B           C

        1         Cat1       Cat2        Cat3

        i         Cati       Catj        Catk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT SeekId,
                CatId,
                ct.Name,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SeekId ORDER BY CatId) AS RN
         FROM   MySeekCatTable sk
                JOIN CatTable ct
                  ON sk.CatId = ct.CatId)
SELECT SeekId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Name END) AS A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Name END) AS B,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Name END) AS C
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY SeekId
```