# SQL Pivot Command

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am looking for some help on designing a simple pivot so that I can link it into other parts of my queries.

My data is like this

Items Table

Below is my table if I run `Select * from items`

```
ITEM      Weight    
12345         10    
12345         11    
654321        50    
654321        20    
654321       100
```

There are hundreds of Items in this table but each item code will only ever have 
maximum of 3 weight records each.

I want the desired output

```
ITEM     Weight_1    Weight_2     Weight_3
12345          10          11         null
654321         50          20          100
```

Would appreciate any suggestions,
I have played around with pivots but each subsequent item puts the weights into weight 4,5,6,7,etc
instead of starting at weight1 for each item.

Thanks

**Update**

Below is what I have used so far,

```
SELECT r.*
FROM   (SELECT 'weight' + CAST(Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY regtime ASC)AS
                               VARCHAR(10))
                      line,
               id,
               weight
        FROM   items it) AS o PIVOT(MIN([weight]) FOR line IN (weight1, weight2,
       weight3)) AS r
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 Pivot on Unknown Number of Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213702/sql-server-2005-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns)

Comment: Could you please give some samples of what you tried?

Comment: Below is what I have used so far,                                                           select r.* from (
 select 'weight' + CAST( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by regtime asc)as varchar(10)) Line,  
id,weight
from items it
) as O
Pivot(MIN([weight]) FOR Line IN (weight1, weight2, weight3)) AS r

Comment: @Robert, when posting new code, please update your question. Do not post code in comments. I did that for you, but make sure you do that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there! You were only missing the `PARTITION BY` clause in `OVER`:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM   (SELECT 'weight' + CAST(Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY
                               regtime ASC)
                                      AS
                                              VARCHAR(10)) line,
               id,
               weight
        FROM   items it) AS o PIVOT(MIN([weight]) FOR line IN (weight1, weight2,
       weight3)) AS r
```

When you `PARTITION BY` by ID, the row numbers are reset for each different ID.

**Update**

You do not need dynamic pivot, since you will always have 3 weights. But, if you ever need dynamic number of columns, take a look at some of the examples here:

- [SQL Server PIVOT perhaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182106/sql-server-pivot-perhaps/7182489#7182489)
- [Pivot data in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232593/pivot-data-in-t-sql/7232755#7232755)
- [How do I build a summary by joining to a single table with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849678/how-do-i-build-a-summary-by-joining-to-a-single-table-with-sql-server/6849795#6849795)

Comment: Thanks Adrian,That worked prefectly ! None of the examples I have found mention the "Partition By Clause"

Answer (score 1):

You will need a value to form the columns which I do with row_number.  The outcome is what you want.  The only negative that I have against PIVOT is that you need to know how many columns in advance.  I use a similar method, but build up the select as dynamic SQL and can then insert my columns.

EDIT: updated to show columns as weight1, weight2, etc.

```
create table #temp (Item int, Weight int)

insert into #temp (Item, Weight) 
Values (12345, 10),
       (12345, 11),
       (654321, 50),
       (654321, 20),
       (654321, 200)

SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT Item,
               Weight,
               'weight' + cast(Row_number() 
                          OVER (partition by Item order by item) as varchar(10)) as seq
          FROM #temp) as Src 
        PIVOT (  MAX(Weight) FOR Seq IN ([Weight1], [Weight2], [Weight3])  ) as PVT
```

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL**
Whenever you need a pivot, use `group_concat` it will output a CSV list of the values you need.
Once you get used to working with it, it's a great tool.

```
SELECT item, GROUP_CONCAT(weight) as weights FROM table1
GROUP BY item
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

**TSQL aka SQL-server**
Many many questions on this because T-SQL supports a `pivot` keyword.

See:
[Transact SQL Query-Pivot-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357756/transact-sql-query-pivot-sql)
[Pivot data in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232593/pivot-data-in-t-sql)

Comment: Hi Johan,Thanks for the quick response. Group_Concat is not a recognised function IN my SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @Robert, if you don't specify which SQL-dialect you use, then it's kind of hard to make the answer specific. I'm not clearvoyant.